# Приведение типов функций

Tags: c++

мне нужно передать функцию

```
void Graphic::display()
```

(Graphic — это мой класс)
в функцию

```
void __stdcall glutDisplayFunction(void (*callback)())
```

проблема в том, что когда я поместил display() в класс, пошли какие-то проблемы с типами (argument of type "void (Graphic::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void(*)()").
Я пытался решить это с помощью

```
glutDisplayFunc(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(&display));
```

и

```
std::function<void()> func = display;
glutDisplayFunc(func);
```

но это тоже не помогло. К тому же, я вообще не понимаю, в чем проблема, если по сути, тип функции не изменился

Comment: `display` - это нестатическая функция-член класса, неявно принимающая скрытый параметр `this` и не может быть использована для передачи в `glutDisplayFunction`. Экземпляр класса `std::function` тем более для этого не годится. Делайте ее статической.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо, получилось! Правда, статические функции вообще не укладываются в концепцию этого класса, поэтому придется все переписывать с нуля

Comment: Одного изменения вполне достаточно. одна дополнительная функция `static void sdisplay(Graphic & g){g.display();}`